# General user profile sync question

Tags: user-profile-service

What is the exact reason the UPS runs under a diffrent account then the farm admin account?

Answer (score 0):

This is for the security purpose. Running UPS using SP_admin can allow the services to run in high privilege mode.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not using the Farm admin account for the UPS is security, Farm admin account is most privileged account in the farm so that's best practices always recommend different accounts.

Even App Pool for UPS running other than Farm admin account but you still need farm admin account to provision the UPA sync and another account which having rights on AD required for sync connection.

http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/01/sharepoint-2013-service-accounts-best-practices-explained.html

http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx